# Devise usable for large-scale applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

out of interest - is devise usable for large scale applications (e.g. Groupon) or better write your own authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes..devise in used in many large scale applications...moreover it has nothing to do much about scaling as  devise will only be used to handle signin/signout/email verification/password management etc which can be also reffered as **ONE TIME CONFIGURATION**.so even if there are million users...it wont affect your performance as you would be dealing with only one table `users`.Recenlty i used devise for an application of online students association involving more than 40k on weekly basis..thats a proof

Answer (score 1):

Spree uses devise for authentication, so a lot of the big e-comerce sites are actually running on devise, we never had any issues with it with any of our clients with large user bases. I used other gems from Plataformatec as well, and they are pretty solid. Good luck with your project!